# How do I schedule a timed reboot of my server in seconds?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, reboot

I’m using bash shell on Linux …

```
$ uname -a
Linux sandbox.mydomain.com 3.4.76-65.111.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 14 21:06:49 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

although it would be nice if I could come up with a solution in any bash supported environment.  My question is, in my script I want to scheduled a delayed reboot of my server in 5 seconds.  So far, I have the below, but it takes 60 seconds …

```
# Timed reboot of server
sudo shutdown -r 1

# Fail if any of the sub-deployments failed.
if [[ ( $PROC1_STATUS -ne 0 ) ||
      ( $PROC2_STATUS -ne 0 ) ||
      ( $PROC3_STATUS -ne 0 ) ]]
then
        exit 1;
fi
```

Does anyone know how I can adjust the above except make the timed reboot in 5 seconds instead of a minute?  The solution doesn't have to use "shutdown" but it was the only tool I could find.

- Dave

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
 sleep 5 ; reboot
```

on your terminal (as root). If you want it in the background, try

```
 ( sleep 5 ; reboot ) &
```

See also [shutdown(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/shutdown.8.html)

Comment: Hi, This seems close but the statements after the "reboot" line don't seem to be getting executed because the system sleeps, the reboot happens and then execution stops.

Comment: Another variant: `nohup sudo -b bash -c 'sleep 5; reboot' &>/dev/null; <other commands>`